# Rendring banner image with text for different mobile screen resolution

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

Hi I m working on a web page, I m finding difficulty in designing banner with text for different mobile widths. So in mobile I want to show only the heading vertically center in all mobile widths, remaining paragraph, content and button should come down. As mobiles will be having different widths depending on that alignments are going bad. Can any body just help me what is the bast way to render this page in mobile only with heading in top, vertically aligned middle and remaining paragraph and button should come down. I m using margins, so plz help me to find the best way except margin.

jsbin link : http://jsbin.com/butore/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: You could use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to finetune the styling for specific size ranges, in your case for mobile only. This is the best way to do it in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Okay if I understand what you want correctly, I would suggest using media queries - you don't need to design for each individual mobile width; that would be horrendous. But find the breaking points where your content is taken out of flow and apply a media query to reduce the margin on that element etc.

Alternatively, you could add a `desktop-only` and `mobile-only` that would change dependant on the device widths you choose. So in your scenario your `mobile-only` class would contain your paragraph and button below the banner.

For example:

```
.desktop-only {
        display:block;
}
.mobile-only {
        display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 45em) {
        .desktop-only {
               display:none;
        }
        .mobile-only {
               display:block; 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned with only mobile devices you could check the user agent and assign a class to the body element based on that. Here's what I've done in the past:

In application controller:

```
def is_phone?
  ua = request.user_agent.try(:downcase)
  if ua =~ /android/ && ua =~ /phone/
    true
  elsif ua =~ /iphone|ipod/ && ua !=~ /ipad/
    true
  elsif ua =~ /blackberry/ && ua !=~ /tablet/
    true
  elsif ua =~ /windows phone/
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
helper_method :is_phone?
```

Then in your layout on your  element:

```
<body class="<%= 'phone' if is_phone? %>">
```

Then in your stylesheet create a section for mobile styles

```
body {
  &.phone {
    /* your phone-specific styles go here */
  }
}
```

Also, I noticed that you tagged your question with Bootstrap, which is responsive out of the box. There's some good documentation here that explains how to do responsive styling using the framework: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid